# Unable to parse jsonarray in laravel, sent from android using volley library

Tags: php, json, laravel

This is volley request code in android app

```
String url = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:80/api/attendances";  //this is address. replaced with xx here
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            for(int i=0; i < studentList.size(); i++)
            {
                jsonArray.put(studentList.get(i).toJson());
            }

            JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject();

            try {
                parameters.put("class_id", class_id);
                parameters.put("students", jsonArray);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    url, parameters,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.d("API", response.toString());

                            try {
                                if(response.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("Success")){

                                }
                                else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), response.getString("msg"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            pDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            // hide the progress dialog
                            VolleyLog.d("API", "Error: " + error.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Unable to contact server.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            if(error.networkResponse.data!=null) {

                                VolleyLog.d("API", "Error: " + body);
                            }
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                        }

                    }){
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    headers.put("Authorization","Bearer "+ token);
                    return headers;
                }
            };

            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest, tag_json_obj);
```

This produces jsonObjectRequest

```
{"class_id":"11","students":[{"id":"222","present":true},{"id":"223","present":true},{"id":"224","present":false}]}
```

Laravel code for this request is -

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'students' => 'required',
        'class_id' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json($validator->errors());
    }
    $user = auth()->user();

    if (Gate::allows('post_attendance')) {
        $attendance = Attendance::create([
            'cl_id' => $request->class_id,
            'user_id' => $user->id,
        ]);

        try {
            $students = json_decode($request->students);
            foreach ($students as $student) {
                Present::create([
                    'attendance_id' => $attendance->id,
                    'student_id' => $student->id,
                    'present' => $student->present
                ]);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            return response()->json(['error', $exception->getMessage()], 300);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'Success',
            'msg' => 'Added'
        ]);
    }


    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'Error',
        'msg' => 'Access Denied!'
    ]);
}
```

If I use android app this code creates an entry in Attendance table but still gives error "BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 300 for http://XX.XX.XX.XX:80/api/attendances". So theres a problem in parsing JSONArray. If i comment out try catch part it runs successfully with status 'Success'.

Also if use API client same Laravel code works perfectly and creates entries in Attendance table as well as Present table.

[image]

In screenshot students field contains students jsonarray given below -

```
[{"id":"222","present":true},{"id":"223","present":true},{"id":"224","present":false}]
```

Problem is I have no idea why request sent from API client is working but but same request is not working on android client, Laravel code works perfectly with API client. But it does work with request sent from android.

I have searched a lot did not find any similar question or a way to debug android client. Volley gives only error response code. Is there any way to access whole error response given by Laravel?
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a `json`  and you can get the json like

```
try {
        $students = json_decode($request->getContent());
        foreach ($students['students'] as $student) {
            Present::create([
                'attendance_id' => $attendance->id,
                'student_id' => $student->id,
                'present' => $student->present
            ]);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        return response()->json(['error', $exception->getMessage()], 300);
    }
```

Use `$request->getContents()` to get the json

Hope this helps

It helped with these tweaks

```
try {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(),true);
        $attendance = Attendance::create([
            'cl_id' => $data['class_id'],
            'user_id' => $user->id,
        ]);
            foreach ($data['students'] as $student) {
                Present::create([
                    'attendance_id' => $attendance->id,
                    'student_id' => $student['id'],
                    'present' => $student['present']
                ]);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            return response()->json(['error', $exception->getMessage()], 300);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Your solution worked with few tweaks